# how to find I accidentally deleted the local history file of android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I accidentally deleted the local history file of android studio. How to recover it because I've losted a lot code. please help me, thank you sirr....

I want to get my code because this is a lot code.

Andriod-Studio Version - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2